# Progress-4GL Writing to log file

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

When running a progress-4gl program, I am able to write to a log file using the log-manager.  However, when writing out message statements they only appear when I use message view-as alert-box.  ie:

```
log-manager:logfile-name = "queue.p"
message "this will not appear".
message "this will appear" view-as alert-box.
```

Will show up in the log file as:

[12/05/10@09:03:21.154-0700] P-11993170 T-000001 1 4GL -- this will appear

Is there any way I can force the log-manager to write out message statements that do **not** include view-as alert-box?  Our legacy code uses the message statement everywhere and I would prefer to not have to go through all related libraries updating it.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect default stream? You won't get messages in the log file, but they'll be written to a file if instead you use an OUTPUT TO... But that depends of your application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear getting messages (without "VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX") to the clientlog file is not possible.

Progress help says: "OpenEdge writes all ABL VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX messages to the log file".
(LOG-ENTRY-TYPES attribute > 4GLMessages).

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of something like the LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE( ) method?

Comment: No, I am thinking of the MESSAGE statement.  Our existing codebase uses MESSAGE extensively to output information to our Appserver log.  I was hoping to be able to use those same libraries without having to go through and add VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX to all the message statements.

Answer (score 1):

you should use in this case a Batch startup parameter. **-b**
then will no messages displayed (except errors).

```
prowin32.exe -p c:\test.p -b
```

you can define, where should be the messages logged. then will not displayed the errors too.
for example:

```
prowin32.exe -p c:\test.p -b > c:\Test.txt
```

Comment: That's actually the current method which is being used.  The problem is that the error messages are displayed to the log without any datetime stamp, which is why I want to start using the log manager